# Skrollr animation flickering in safari. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: animation, safari, skrollr

While scrolling down through a image animation it flickers between each image. When scrolling back up and starting over, the flickering goes away. Works perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox. Heres the code structure:

```
HTML

<div class="container" id="arena"> 
            <div id="animate"
            data-anchor-target="#arena" 
            data-smooth-scrolling="off"

            >
                  <img class="lazy" src="img/animations/ctu_hq_animation_mb_4.0001.png" alt="" data-0-top="display:none;" data--100-top="display:block;" data--125-top="display:none;">
                  <img class="lazy" src="img/animations/ctu_hq_animation_mb_4.0003.png" alt="" data-0-top="display:none;" data--125-top="display:block;" data--150-top="display:none;">
                  <img class="lazy" src="img/animations/ctu_hq_animation_mb_4.0004.png" alt="" data-0-top="display:none;" data--150-top="display:block;" data--175-top="display:none;">
</div>

CSS: 

img {
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
    position: fixed;
}


    #arena {
        position: relative;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 900px;
        background-size: 900px 800px;
    }
    #animate {
        width: 850px;
        height: 650px;
        position: fixed;
        background-size: 900px 800px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        left: 10%;


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, img {position: fixed) was the problem. Remove and solves the problem